# Bootstrap textarea align right css

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap with jquery and I am trying to figure out how to have this textarea line up on the right side of the screen instead of the left. Will someone please assist me in how to move it to the right side of the screen.

```
<div class="col-xs-7">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="overdueSection" class="col-xs-6">
        <label class="centered" for="overdueWindow">OVERDUE BATCH</label>
        <textarea type="text" name="overdueWindow" id="overdueWindow" class="form-control" rows="7"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pvyk3hps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to achieve this

1) Custom CSS

```
#overdueWindow {
 float: right
}
```

2) Using Bootstrap `push-*`classes

```
<div id="overdueSection" class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-6">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the Bootstrap class `pull-right`

```
<div id="overdueSection" class="col-xs-6 pull-right">
```